# Can anyone identify this queen ant?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

I caught my first queen but I'm having trouble identifying her. Could anyone help me out? She has a reddish brown body and black legs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's important to get a clear picture and to have some sort of scale for species identification.

Comment: Probably not very accurately...

Comment: It's hard. I'll try to get a better picture tomorrow